# R - browseURL alternative

Tags: r

I have a PHP file, that once executed, downloads some data from the internet into some files in my FTP server. I am using browseURL to delegate this execution:

```
browseURL(composeURL)
```

Although I have to update my project just once a week, I cannot rely on other alternatives (like cronjobs) because composeURL is dinamically built in R depending on a wide number of variables.

browseURL does its job, but what I don't like too much is that the browser is actually opened (yes I know, that is what all is about). In browseURL documentation, however, I can read:

> The default browser is set by option "browser", in turn set by the
>   environment variable R_BROWSER if that is set, otherwise to NULL. To
>   suppress showing URLs altogether, use the value "false"

`browseURL(composeURL, browser= "false")`, however, seems to do literally nothing. Maybe I am not correctly understanding what this parameter does.

While I was still updating my project with MS Excel, I could hide Internet Explorer and "call the PHP file in a background process" using VBA. My question is: is there an alternative to browseURL able to "silently" call the PHP file?

Comment: On about the third line of `browseURL()`, there is `if (identical(browser, "false")) return(invisible())`.  So it seems like it did nothing, but it actually did execute your `browse` argument

Comment: To download a file from the internet, you can use download.file("URL") command

Comment: You could also open a connection to an ftp server, see `?connections`

Comment: @RichardScriven thanks for the feedback. Then it has to be something wrong with my config, because my files aren't updated with the parameter `browser = "false"`. However, as soon as I delete it, it all works as expected. Also many thanks for the `?connections` hint. `url(composeURL, open = "r")` does what I need!

Comment: @Sathish, I have to admit, that I was initially exceptic as I didn't wanted to donwload the file, just execute it. But using `download.file(composeURL, "foo")` also does its works.